# How to write a file and read that file again into temporary file

Tags: java, swing

```
edit "second version"
```

I have building an Java swing using ANTLR to get the tree of source code. For get the tree image that build from ANTLR, I am using GRAPHVIZ, http://www.graphviz.org/ .

So, Graphviz will be write to a file that have extension .dot and then I will load it into my Swing application. My code is like this

```
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

        File tempInput;
        try {
            tempInput = File.createTempFile("output", ".dot", tempDir);
            File tempOutput = File.createTempFile("tree", ".png", tempDir);

            if (OS.equals("Linux")) {

                try {

                    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempInput.getAbsoluteFile()));
                    bw.write(st2);
                    bw.close();

                    Process pr = rt.exec("dot -Tpng  /tmp/output.dot -o "
                            + "/tmp/tree.png");

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("failed to write the image file");
                }

            } else {

                try {

                    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempInput.getAbsoluteFile()));
                    bw.write(st2);
                    bw.close();

                    String dotPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\\bin\\dot.exe";
                    String fileInputPath = tempInput.toString();
                    String fileOutputPath = tempOutput.toString();
                    String tParam = "-Tpng";
                    String tOParam = "-o";

                    String[] cmd = new String[5];
                    cmd[0] = dotPath;
                    cmd[1] = tParam;
                    cmd[2] = fileInputPath;
                    cmd[3] = tOParam;
                    cmd[4] = fileOutputPath;

                    rt.exec(cmd);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to write to file");
                } finally {

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainAlgoritma.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

you know, the output in windows should be named tree.png. But windows not gives me that name. The name is dynamically change like 
tree2593490478729479216.png and sometimes like tree9133268802668231475.png and etc .

My question is :

1. how to get the name just tree.png ?
2. how to delete the image after process after the image is read and loaded to app ?

   edit

Now, how to read that image and then load it into app... ?
I make a class again to load the image, but you know, I am still confused.

```
private BufferedImage image;
String tmpfolder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

public FileImage() {

    if (OS.equals("Linux")) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(tmpfolder+"/tree.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Image failed to load..!!! ");
        }
    } else {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(tmpfolder+"\\tree.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Image failed to load...!!! ");
        }
    }

    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    jPanel3.add(jLabel);

}
```

Comment: The tag `antlr` does not belong to this question: please don't put it back again.

Comment: Oke, Mr Bart. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding an absolute path, you can use relative paths or use a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) in Swing to open a file chooser that will let the user select a file for input and/or for output.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the name just tree.png

You should read the javadoc of the [`createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) method you are using. It clearly states that the strings you pass in as parameters are a prefix and suffix.

If you replace

```
File.createTempFile("output", ".dot", tempDir);
```

by

```
tempInput = new File( tempDir, "output.dot" );
tempInput.createNewFile();
```

it should work.

Note how I used the `File` constructor taking two arguments. This avoids the ugly switch statement on the OS you are using.

Comment: mr.Robin, where is " tempInput = new File(tempDir, "output.dot").createNewFile();"  it is error. Netbeans says incompatible file : boolean cannot be converted to file

Comment: @user2971238 I updated my answer. But I you would have read the javadoc of those methods, you should have been able to figure this out yourself